# Bootstrap timepicker : minuteStep

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I have 2 time picker controls on my page, `fromTime` and `toTime`. I want to set the `minuteStep` of `toTime` dynamically in such a way that the difference between both the times is in multiple of 60.

ie. if `fromTime` is 2.15 -  then `toTime` can have values like 3.15,4.15,5.15 etc

```
var myDate = Globalize.format(new Date(1990, 1, 1, 23, 00), 'd');
var StartTime = Globalize.parseDate(myDate + " " + $('#txtStartTime').val(), Globalize.culture().calendar.patterns.d + " " + Globalize.culture().calendar.patterns.t);

var startMinutes = (StartTime.getMinutes());
$('#txtEndTime').timepicker({
    minuteStep: startMinutes
});
```

Comment: Which timepicker are you using?